# Increase search result snippet length on Google Search Applicance

Tags: google-search-appliance

Is there a possibility to increase the length of the search result snippet (RES/R/S in XML output) provided by the GSA? Either per frontend or in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default number of search results for a single query is 100. Maximum number is 1000.

You can increase the default number of search results by using the `num` query parameter.

Source: https://support.google.com/gsa/answer/4411411?hl=en#results

Update:

To Change the Snippet Length

By default the Search Appliance, for most languages, will return Snippets with the length of 160 characters. Some exceptions to this rule are CJK languages for which Snippets are by default 240 characters.

Search > Search Features > Query Settings > Snippets Generation > Snippet Length

Source: http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/admin_console_help/serve_query_expansion.html

Comment: That would be easy. But my problem is increasing the length of the search result snippet of a single search result in the XML itself, not the number of results for a single query.

Comment: where to select these settings? Search > Search Features > Query Settings > Snippets Generation > Snippet Length